Is it possible to generate and build java client during project build time?
Im using openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate java client from an openapi spec but i dont want to manage a git repository for that so i generated the client's source code into my target folder during generate-sources phase.
Turns out it wasnt a great idea, because maven will use the project's dependencies to compile the client instead of the generated pom.xml which leads to some unexpected behaviour, like serialization issues.
My other idea was to generate it as a submodule but i dont know if this is possible or not because maven will freak out if one of the submodules doesnt exist and i dont really want to track generated code in my repository.
Is there a way to generate and compile the client artifact during project build time without having to add its source to the vcs?

Of course that should be doable... the question is what you have so far? Which JDK, Which Mave version? Which Version of openapi generator etc. ?

@khmarbaise Im using java 8 (zulu-1.8.0_392), maven 3.9.3 and openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.2.1 but i can change any of these versions except java.

There is an example java client on github.
